# How do i make enemy AI face the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find a way to rotate the enemy towards the player. Currently it follows/stops and shoots the player. Have not figured out how to make it rotate. Please help if you can. I've tried couple of different things on here but they dont seem to work.

I've tried creating a Flip function with isFacingRight.

```
private bool facingRight;
public float speed;
public float stoppingDistance;
public float retreatDistance;
private Animator enemyAnimation;
private bool isDead;
private float direction;
public static bool enemyShoot = false;

private float timeBtwShots;
public float startTimeBtwShots;

public GameObject projectile;
private Transform player;

[SerializeField]
private Stat health;

private void Awake()
{
    health.Initialize();
}


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Player tag
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    enemyAnimation = GetComponent<Animator>();


    isDead = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > stoppingDistance)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;


  if(player.position.x > transform.position.x && !facingRight) //if the target is to the right of enemy and the enemy is not facing right
    Flip();
 if(player.position.x < transform.position.x && facingRight)
    Flip();
    }
   else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position,player.position) <= stoppingDistance && Vector2.Distance(transform.position,player.position)>retreatDistance)
    {
        transform.position = this.transform.position;


    }
    else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) > retreatDistance)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1f, 1f);
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        timeBtwShots = 100;
        enemyAnimation.SetTrigger("Attack");
    }

    if (enemyShoot == true)
    {
        //Stops animation Loop
        enemyShoot = false;
        enemyAnimation.SetTrigger("Shoot");


    }

    if (timeBtwShots <= 0)
    {
        Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        timeBtwShots = startTimeBtwShots;
    }
    else
    {
        timeBtwShots -= Time.deltaTime;
    }


    if (health.CurrentVal == 0)
    {

        timeBtwShots = 100;
        FindObjectOfType<SoundsScript>().Play("SaibaDeath");
        isDead = true;
        enemyAnimation.SetBool("Dead", isDead);
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "ProjectileEnem")
    {
        health.CurrentVal -= 50;
        enemyAnimation.SetTrigger("Hurt");
    }

}

//Disables enemeies when off screen
private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    GetComponent <Enemy> ().enabled = false;
}
//Re enables enemies once they are visible
private void OnBecameVisible()
{
    GetComponent<Enemy>().enabled = true;
}

void Flip(){
      Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
      scale.x *= -1;
      transform.localScale = scale;
      facingRight = !facingRight;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add what you attempted to make them face the player?  I don't see your flip function or `isFacingRight` in the code you provided.  Also is this a topdown perspective or like a platformer perspective(Asking because you say rotate, but you also mention a flip function and isFacingRight)

Comment: void Flip(){
      Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
      scale.x *= -1;
      transform.localScale = scale;
      facingRight = !facingRight;
}

and put this into Update
 if(target.position.x > transform.position.x && !facingRight) //if the target is to the right of enemy and the enemy is not facing right
        Flip();
     if(target.position.x < transform.position.x && facingRight)
        Flip();

It's a 2D platformer

Comment: Add it to your question. along with any conditions used to trigger it.

Comment: Added flip function with code in update

Comment: Pass in a value to flip, such as `float direction` make it 1 for isRight and -1 for !isRight instead of constantly multiplying by -1, this will help us remove any possible bugs that could arise.

Comment: Your code looks like it might work. However, you're doing the flips only when they are further than `stoppingDistance`. Maybe move those two flip `if`s outside of the outer `if`s?

Comment: Didn't work, tried all outer ifs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spriteRenderer.flipX = transform.position.x < player.position.x;
```

`SpriteRenderer` contains the `flipX` and `flipY` property, you do not need to create your own `Flip()` function.

You need a reference to the `SpriteRenderer` on your GameObject.

The above code is assuming that your sprite faces left on default. If your sprite faces right normally, change the `<` to `>`.

Comment: This is a 2D game, this would not work well. Potentially the character may look up-ish.

Comment: "transform doesnt contain a definition for x" error, how can i fix this?

Comment: @Tomajuli See now

Comment: It flips it, but doesnt flip back, i got to make a new function that manages this or can i plug this into the code above somewhere?